# Webdriver grid run tests on different browsers

Tags: selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to distribute my tests on different browsers (in the same node) I am using Selenium Grid.

Here is my code  :

```
@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeTest

public void setup (String browser) throws IOException  

{
    File file = new File("config.properties");
    FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(fileInput);
    fileInput.close();
    TestURL = properties.getProperty("AppURL");
    BaseURL = properties.getProperty("HubURL");
    winURL = properties.getProperty("WinURL");





        DesiredCapabilities capability=null;

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
            System.out.println("firefox");
            capability= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capability.setBrowserName("firefox"); 
            capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
            //capability.setVersion("");
        }

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
            File chromedriver = new File("C:\\grid\\chromedriver_win32_2.3");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriver.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("chrome");
            capability= DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capability.setBrowserName("chrome"); 
            capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);


            //capability.setVersion("");
        }


    driver = new RemoteWebDriver ( new URL ( winURL ),  capability) ;
    driver.get(TestURL);
      WebElement input1 = driver.findElement(By.id("login_form_user_input"));
      input1.sendKeys("guest");
      WebElement input2 = driver.findElement(By.id("login_form_password_input"));
      input2.sendKeys("guest");
      WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.id("login_form_signin_button"));
      btn.click();






}
```

And here is my testng.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
       <suite name="Basic Web Elements" thread-count="2" parallel="tests" >
       <test name="Home Page load time on firefox">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="basicWebElements.HomePage" />
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Home Page load time on Internet Explorer">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="basicWebElements.HomePage" />
    </classes>
</test>
 </suite>
```

However when I run testng XML i get this error :
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Please not that my chromedriver is saved in my node in the path mentioned in the code above and that my ENV variable PATH is pointing to the driver exec file.

I am launching my hub by executing this batch file :

```
set HERE=%CD%
set JAVA_HOME=%HERE%\jdk1.7.0_40
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set SELENIUM_VERSION=2.35.0
set CHROME_VERSION=chromedriver_win32_2.3
set HUB_URL=http://localhost:4444/grid/register
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-%SELENIUM_VERSION%.jar  -role hub
```

And launching my node this way :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role webdriver -hub   http://*.*.*.*:4444/grid/register  -port 5556
```

I am out of ideas why my tests are running fine on Firefox but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the chromedriver path while starting your node like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role webdriver -hub   http://*.*.*.*:4444/grid/register  -port 5556 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path_to_chromedriver_in_node
```

This will set the chromedriver path correctly.

In your case, are you having the java code in the node or a different machine? Your java code

```
File chromedriver = new File("C:\\grid\\chromedriver_win32_2.3");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriver.getAbsolutePath());
```

will be executed in the machine where the code is physically available. I have often seen people keeping this code in Hub and complaining that chromedriver is not getting set in node. That might be reason in your case as well.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. If I set the chrome driver in the path will this mean that for this node I will only be able to launch my tests with chrome (in my case I want to be able to launch different browsers in the same node). And yes I am having my code in the hub so you second comment is relevant but not sure what should I do then? give the network path of the machine?

Comment: @Ziwdigforbugs This property will be read by seleniumserver only for launching chrome. It does not affect your ability to launch tests on other browser. If you have multiple nodes which needs the chromedriver, then setting up the file in a common shared location would make sense

Comment: I have launched my node this way :

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role webdriver -hub   http://*.*.*.*:4444/grid/register  -port 5556 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver= C:\grid\chromedriver_win32_2.3\chromedriver.exe however I am getting this error now : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\grid

Comment: @Ziwdigforbugs And the node contains chromedriver in this path?C:\grid\chromedriver_win32_2.3\chromedriver.exe.

Comment: Yes AJ!! the executable files is located in that path.

Comment: When you run this command in node, do you see a line of code in terminal which says - setting property webdriver.chrome.driver...?

Comment: yes here is what I get :                                       C:\grid>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role webdriver -hub   http://10.2.128.126:4444/grid/register  -
port 5556 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver= C:\grid\chromedriver_win32_2.3\chromedriver.exe
dÚc. 04, 2013 11:29:17 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid node
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to
11:29:18.632 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.0-b56
11:29:18.632 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
11:29:18.648 INFO - v2.35.0, with Core v2.35.0. Built from revision...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42484/discussion-between-a-j-and-ziwdigforbugs)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that in your path you are not appending the ".exe" .Have you tried the below code modification

```
File chromedriver = new File("C:\\grid\\chromedriver_win32_2.3.exe");
```

FWIW the code I use to set Chromedriver is:

```
if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")){
            String chromeProp= System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/lib/chromedriver.exe";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",chromeProp);

            driver = new ChromeDriver();
```